# Where can I find console log of lite-server?

Tags: console, truffle, lite-server, distributed-apps

I’m now developing a simple Dapp using Truffle.

When command `npm run dev` is submitted, the console mode changes as below.
[image: screenshot of console]

Therefore, even though “console.log(message for debug here)” is written in JavaScript file of Dapp, I cannot receive the log message since console mode has changed to browser sync mode. Does anyone know how or where console log of lite-server can be found?

Comment: In browser's console? https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Answer (score 0):

F12 shows up developer tool including console.